# Proofs of the second fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, integration

I am referring to the following version of the theorem, in the setting of the Lebesgue integral.

**Theorem** Let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \bf R$ be an *everywhere* differentiable function whose derivative is Lebesgue integrable. Then $$\int_a^b f'(x) \, dx = f(b) - f(a).$$

There is a proof of this result in the standard textbook of W. Rudin, [*Real and Complex Analysis*](https://www.scribd.com/doc/14868434/W-rudin-Real-and-Complex-Analysis) (theorem 8.21) relying on a Vitali-Caratheodory theorem which I don't find very enlightening. I think I also saw a proof based on a maximal inequality, I can't remember where though.

Are there any other ways to prove this result? A short proof? References are welcome.

Comment: The link to RCA does not work anymore.